# Windows 10 not detected on installation of Ubuntu on a second SSD

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I own an Acer PC with Windows 10 pre-installed on the main SSD drive. 
I added a second SSD drive on which I want to install Ubuntu-studio, from a USB drive generated by Rufus.

I managed to launch the Ubuntu installer, but it only detects the new second (and empty) SSD disk. **The main disk containing Windows is not detected**. So, no option such as "Install along Windows" is proposed.

I selected the option "something else" and I created manually 4 partitions on this new SSD drive: 1 UEFI (otherwise, the installer displays many alarms saying that there ***must*** be a UEFI partition), 1 swap, 1 main partition for root, and a fourth partition for `/home`.

I completed the installation process and restarted the PC.
Ubuntu launched properly, but **without displaying first the multi-boot screen to select either Windows or Ubuntu**. This means I could not access Windows anymore. So, I uninstalled Ubuntu and its relative boot scripts.

According to the Windows *msinfo* command, my version of Windows is in UEFI BIOS Mode. I also disabled the security boot in the BIOS interface. So, I do not understand why this disk is not detected by Ubuntu.

Is there any idea of what can solve this?

Comment: Most common issue is that Windows fast start up is on. Some with SSD may need firmware update to both UEFI & SSD. Or drive not AHCI. And Acer typically needs 'trust' setting to convert 'unknown' UEFI boot entry to "Ubuntu" or whatever you name it. You should always be able to directly boot Windows from Acer's UEFI boot menu. What model Acer. Trust setting is same on all models. Newer Acer -  CTRL S on the main Tab in BIOS to get the option to change SATA to AHCI http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this reply. I managed to set most of the parameters you mentionned in the BIOS, but the situation is still the same.
By the way, I forgot to mention that neither Windows is detected nor the Windows disk itself !  Ubuntu only sees the small empty drive. This is probably the reason why Windows is not detected either.
I do not know if it has any effect, by I noticed that, when I display the disks list in Windows, the first disk (No 0) is the empty one on which I want to install Ubuntu, and the second disk (No 1) is the main disk on which Windows is installed.
This seems not disturbing Windows boot, that finds the right disk, but can it be a problem for Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

Another idea in real-time : The interface of the main SSD disk, that is not detected by Ubuntu installer,  is : M.2 - PCI-E. I have very little knowledge on these hardware considerations, but I guess this is something different from the traditional SATA interface.
Is there any known problem for Ubuntu installation with this kind of Disk interface ? 
Thanks.